# Word Wrap in Go

Tags: go

I'm building a dead simple CLI app that parses a RSS feed and prints it to `stdout`. I needed a simple word wrapping function to, well, wrap lines to an arbitrary length (say 80 or 120 chars).

I ended up using this, as it gets the job done. However, as I'm still new to Go, I was wondering if this can be improved?

```
func wordWrap(text string, lineWidth int) (wrapped string) {
    words := strings.Fields(strings.TrimSpace(text))
    if len(words) == 0 {
        return text
    }
    wrapped = words[0]
    spaceLeft := lineWidth - len(wrapped)
    for _, word := range words[1:] {
        if len(word)+1 > spaceLeft {
            wrapped += "\n" + word
            spaceLeft = lineWidth - len(word)
        } else {
            wrapped += " " + word
            spaceLeft -= 1 + len(word)
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Here's a working sample code - https://play.golang.org/p/i24iSnpTjtP

Comment: Seems fine to me. But remember that if your text has any leading or trailing `'\t', '\n', '\v', '\f', '\r', ' ', U+0085 (NEL), U+00A0 (NBSP)`, etc., then they would be trimmed by `strings.TrimSpace`.

Comment: @shmsr:  `strings.Fields` removes all `unicode.IsSpace` characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> working sample code - https://play.golang.org/p/i24iSnpTjtP

---

Really!

```
sample := "This is a rather long line that needs word wrapping to an arbirtary line lenght so it's easier to read it."
```

Check your spelling.

```
sample := "This is a rather long line that needs word wrapping to an arbitrary line length so it's easier to read it."
```

---

UTF-8 is a variable-length encoding. `len(word)` is the length of `word` in bytes, not characters (except for ASCII). For example, test using Greek and Russian (Google Translate) samples:

```
sample := `Αυτή είναι μια μάλλον μεγάλη γραμμή που χρειάζεται αναδίπλωση λέξεων σε αυθαίρετη γραμμή μήκος, ώστε να είναι πιο εύκολο να το διαβάσετε.`

sample := `Это довольно длинная линия, которая нуждается в перенос слов в произвольную строку длина, так что это легче читать.`
```

---

```
words := strings.Fields(strings.TrimSpace(text)))
```

Since `strings.Fields` removes `uinicode.IsSpace` characters, isn't `strings.TrimSpace` superfluous?

---

Why do you make multiple passes (directly and indirectly) of `text` when one will do?

Why do you make so many allocations when one or two will do?

```
BenchmarkBaduker-4   455914   2738 ns/op   1632 B/op   21 allocs/op
BenchmarkPeterSO-4   592740   1760 ns/op    224 B/op    2 allocs/op
```

`peterso.go` https://play.golang.org/p/F1qyJRKurpq :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func wordWrap(text string, lineWidth int) string {
    wrap := make([]byte, 0, len(text)+2*len(text)/lineWidth)
    eoLine := lineWidth
    inWord := false
    for i, j := 0, 0; ; {
        r, size := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(text[i:])
        if size == 0 && r == utf8.RuneError {
            r = ' '
        }
        if unicode.IsSpace(r) {
            if inWord {
                if i >= eoLine {
                    wrap = append(wrap, '\n')
                    eoLine = len(wrap) + lineWidth
                } else if len(wrap) > 0 {
                    wrap = append(wrap, ' ')
                }
                wrap = append(wrap, text[j:i]...)
            }
            inWord = false
        } else if !inWord {
            inWord = true
            j = i
        }
        if size == 0 && r == ' ' {
            break
        }
        i += size
    }
    return string(wrap)
}

func main() {
    sample := "This is a rather long line that needs word wrapping to an arbitrary line length so it's easier to read it."
    fmt.Printf("%s\n\n", wordWrap(sample, 40))
    greek := `Αυτή είναι μια μάλλον μεγάλη γραμμή που χρειάζεται αναδίπλωση λέξεων σε αυθαίρετη γραμμή μήκος, ώστε να είναι πιο εύκολο να το διαβάσετε.`
    fmt.Printf("%s\n\n", wordWrap(greek, 40))
    russian := `Это довольно длинная линия, которая нуждается в перенос слов в произвольную строку длина, так что это легче читать.`
    fmt.Printf("%s\n\n", wordWrap(russian, 40))
}
```

Comment: your reviews are truly eye-opening. I appreciate your time and effort!

Comment: This code may be more efficient, but I found the original code much easier to understand.